# C++: variables vs references?

Tags: c++, variables, reference, initialization, declaration

So I see a lot of questions on references vs pointers, but my confusions are what's the difference between a variable and a reference. e.g. the following code:

```
int main() {
    int ival = 1024;
    int &refVal = ival;
    cout << "refVal " << refVal << endl;
    cout << "&refVal " << &refVal << endl;
    cout << "&ival " << &ival << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

These are the outputs:

```
refVal 1024
&refVal 0x7fff5f45b968
&ival 0x7fff5f45b968
```

So we see `refVal` and `ival` have exactly the same address (?), and the same value. Are they just the same thing?

I am also curious on what exactly happens with the `int ival = 1024` statement. I imagine something like this:

- a literal object of type `int` is created in memory with value 1024
- a variable, `ival` is bind to this object. **Is `ival` a reference to that literal object?**
- I imagine `ival` will occupy some memory block too, is this correct?
- is `refVal` bind to `iVal`, or is `refVal` bind to the literal object (1024) that `ival` is also bind to?

Thanks!

**Update 13 hours later:**

Thanks again for the replies. If I may, I'd like to add some context that I think contributes to my confusion:

- I got the example code from section 2.3.1 of the book *C++ Primer*, which was on references. It did not explain how references are used, and I think that got me confused. In particular. if `ival` and `refval` are just two names for the same object, why do we need the concept "reference" at all?
- It makes more sense to me that in the context of passing a variable to a function, by-reference saves some memory than by-value.
- I am still unsure why we would want a standalone reference to a variable.

Comment: A variable is a container where a value is stored. A reference to that variable is pointing to some address in memory. This is basic c++ knowledge.

Comment: There's no "difference" - variables and references are totally distinct concepts, and variables can be of reference types!

Comment: @Sailanarmo Thanks for the comment. "A reference to that variable is pointing to some address in memory." Does that reference have memory location, too? How exactly is "pointing" implemented?

Comment: In your example, refVal has the value of 1024. It stores it at the address 0x7fff5f45b968. You then print out the address of refVal, you then set ival equal to the address of refVal and ask to print it out. So think of it as refVal->address.

Comment: @yuqli How exactly it is implemented depends on your target machine architecture and compiler vendor. An "average" implementation would just use pointers, that is memory addressing.

Comment: At this point you may as well study a bit of (dis)assembly for a couple of popular architectures (e.g. x86 and ARM) to understand the underlying mechanics better.

Comment: A lot of this depends on how a reference is implemented. It might not be the address-based set up Sailanarmo describes. It could merely be the compiler using two names for the same variable. Anywhere the compiler can save some work without you noticing, it generally will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a reference [*is* a variable](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#6). A reference is *not* an object of its own however. A reference is an entity that refers to an existing object.

While the compiler will in many cases (but not necessarily always) use the same mechanism (i.e., the passing around of addresses) by which pointers are implemented to also implement a reference, at the language level, pointers and references are completely different things. They both essentially express an indirection. However, a pointer is its own object with its own address, it needs to explicitly be dereferenced and its value can be changed. A reference is not an object itself (it, e.g., does not have an address or size), it's an entity that refers to an existing object.

The statement

```
int ival = 1024;
```

is a declaration as well as a definition of an object of type `int` that is initialized to the value 1024. So yes, an `int` object is created and the name `ival` is introduced. From that point on, `ival` is an [*id-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id) that denotes that particular `int` object.

The statement

```
int &refVal = ival;
```

is a declaration and definition of a reference that refers to the `int` object designated by the expression `ival`. From that point on, the name `refVal` is an *id-expression* that denotes that object. So yes, the names `refVal` and `ival` both designate *the same* `int` object.

Note that while both `ival` and `refVal` are variables, there is only one object created by the two declaration statements above, which is the `int` object defined by the declaration that introduced `ival`.

In general, the name `ival` itself will only require storage in the internal data structures (symbol tables) used by your compiler and linker during compilation. `ival` is just a name you use in your code to identify an object. The compiled machine code will simply access whatever object that identifier identified accordingly (e.g., through its address). There is no need to explicitly represent names during runtine of your program (except for dynamic linking and debugging information). You will most likely not find the string "ival" anywhere in your compiled (release) binary.

Comment: Thanks for the painstaking answer and references(!). This makes much more sense, as one of my original confusion is **there should not be any differences in types/relative standings between `ival` and `refVal`**. In other words, if `refVal` is a reference to `ival`, then it should also hold that `ival` is a reference to `refVal` as well! They should have the same reference/variable relation both ways around! So the first statement you wrote - that a variable is a reference, really made things much clearer.

Comment: @yuqli Just to make sure: A reference *can* be a variable. But an object can *also* be a variable. In general, a variable is a reference *or* an object. But not every reference is a variable. And not every variable is a reference. `refVal` is not a reference to the name `ival`, it's a reference to the object that `ival` designates. And `ival` is not a reference to `refVal`. [There can be no references to references](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#5). Both `ival` and `refVal` designate the same object. But the reference `refVal` itself is not an object, so it cannot be referred to.

Comment: You can think of `refVal` as a name that is bound to whatever it is initialized with.

Comment: See your point. Thanks for pointing it out. A reference is not an object and thus can not have reference to it. I think I need to read on references / pointers ...

Answer (score 3):

`int ival` : this is a real existed allocated space in stack part of memory.

`int &refVal` : this is only another name of 'ival', no allocated space for it.

`'&refVal'` equals `'&ival'`, both of them get the memory address of the variable `'ival'`.

Comment: It's actually unspecified whether space is allocated for a reference. And both are equally "real". +1 for "only another name" though, it's the most accurate summary IMO.

Comment: @StoryTeller Agree only partially. It's most accurate for *given example*, but not for the general case (consider function parameters of reference type!). The question does not give me the impression that it is *limited* to this example, so I consider this answer as incomplete.

Comment: @Aconcagua - The function parameters make absolutely no difference. It's still just a name for some object. The object may or may not have been named previously, but the allegory still holds. It's IMO the most intuitive way to consider references.

Comment: @StoryTeller Function parameters make a difference in such that you can't get around allocating memory for - which this answer states different, though.

Comment: @Aconcagua - Can you site the standard on this? And this answer says no such thing. It discussing `refVal` only, and presents a useful allegory. It was you who brought up function parameters, please don't straw-man this answer now.

Comment: @StoryTeller *"no allocated space for it"* If that part is dropped or modified appropriately, I can accept the allegory even for function parameters.

Comment: A smart enough compiler given the option will allocate no space for a reference. It doesn't happen as often as I'd like, but the standard leaves the possibility open.

Comment: @Aconcagua - "*It*" being `refVal`. And I too pointed out it's best not to speak in such absolutes. So I really don't see what's the point of this arguing, other than it being for the sake of arguing.

Comment: *"**e.g.** the following code"* - this is what made me see the question in a broader scope, including function parameters as well. Do I misinterpret "e. g." here (as non-native English speaker)?

Answer (score 2):

Internally, a reference is just a pointer, the main difference being you don't need to use syntax specific to pointers and it can never be `NULL`.

It is mostly useful for passing arguments to functions, because the only other way of passing an object as argument to a function without copying it is with pointers, and then you have to use pointer syntax everywhere. Passing as reference keeps your code significantly cleaner and consistent.

A reference can never exist by itself, it will always refer to an existing variable.

Comment: "can never be null" - actually, it can be the result of dereferencing a nullptr, so technically...

Comment: @Aconcagua Yeah technically you can cheat the rules and make it do what it's not supposed to, but then you're invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Rather having in view function parameters of reference type. Caller might accidentally assign a `nullptr` because of having forgotten to check before. Sure, UB (totally aware of), a bug in code, but still...

Comment: @Aconcagua - Creating a null reference does not happen by accident - it requires deliberate steps by a programmer.    I've encountered too many programmers who claim that is an "accident", and - when asked - they say something like "It wasn't compiling so I introduced a cast .....   and then it crashed at run time".   Well, doh!  They've deliberately bludgeoned the compiler into submission by explicitly creating a NULL pointer of the required type in a way that prevents the compiler diagnosing errors, then dereferenced that pointer.   That's no accident.

Comment: @Peter `void g(X& x) { /*...*/ } void f(X* x) { /*...*/ if(x) g(*x); /*...*/ }` would be the correct version, but some coder might have forgotten the if check - then it *is* an accident...

Comment: Ah, got the point: Accident or not, as we dereference a nullptr, we *already* have UB *before* assignment. So in this respect, need to accept "cannot" in sense of "without having invoked UB"...

Comment: @Aconcagua - if someone is obtaining a reference from a pointer, the onus is to either ensure the pointer is valid (e.g. by design that ensures the pointer cannot be null) or to check first.     Yes, programmers claim it is an accident.   But it is really sloppy work.

Comment: @Peter Can't contradict any further. But you can't imagine how often I've already seen "really sloppy work" even in production code...

Comment: @Aconcagua - I wish I couldn't imagine that.   Unfortunately, I've seen it a lot too.

Answer (score 1):

> So we see refVal and ival have exactly the same address (?), and the
>   same value. Are they just the same thing?

No, `ival` is a variable: it has its own allocated stack memory in this case. `refVal` is just a name *bound* to it which you could potentially pass on to a function without copying the entire memory of `ival` to a local variable in the function (important, as variables could be much bigger than an `int`)

```
int func1(int arg)
int func2(int& arg);

int var = 0;
int& varRef = var;

func1(var); // Entire memory of var is copied into the param named arg.
func2(varRef) // Just the address of 'var' is copied.
```

A reference cannot be *rebound*, and any assignments to the variable reference are mere assignments to the referenced variable.

```
varRef = 1; // 'var' itself now has the value of '1'.
```

> a literal object of type int is created in memory with value 1024

Not quite, this isn't python.

> a variable, ival is bind to this object. Is ival a reference to that
>   literal object?

Nop, no *binding* is performend here. Just regular assignment. iVal is a variable of type int.

> I imagine ival will occupy some memory block too, is this correct?

Correct, it has stack allocated block in the size of an `int`.

> is refVal bind to iVal, or is refVal bind to the literal object (1024)
>   that ival is also bind to?

Again, as there is no third "literal" object here, only iVal representing the `int` block of memory and `refVal` being bound to `iVal`.

Answer (score 0):

Well the different by the two is

variable:
A variable provides us with named storage that our programs can manipulate. Each variable in C++ has a specific type, which determines the size and layout of the variable's memory; the range of values that can be stored within that memory; and the set of operations that can be applied to the variable.

Reference:
A reference variable is an alias, that is, another name for an already existing variable. Once a reference is initialized with a variable, either the variable name or the reference name may be used to refer to the variable.

it's base on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/

Well if you still don't understand it look at this code

```
 //Pointer
int *p0 ,*p1;
int firstv = 10, secondv = 20;
p0 = &firstv;
p1 = &secondv;
*p0 = 30; // first = 30
*p1 = *p0; // second = 30
std::cout << firstv << std::endl;
std::cout << secondv << std::endl;
p0 = p1; // p0 is pointing at secondv
*p0 = 50; // secondv is now = to 50
std::cout << firstv << std::endl;
std::cout << secondv << std::endl;
```

well in short reference is an alias as said above, what it does is it just referring to the variable, Once it refers to that variable it will just be like A = &B and what can it do is basically just, when you change the variable A the variable B will also change because it's referring to that variable, as you see at the examples about the p0 is referring to the firstv and when we change the *p0 = 30  (the value that's been pointing by p0 is = to 30) in line 6 the firstv will be equal to 30

and the variable is just a storage

summary:
variable is just a storage
reference is an address that you use to refer a variable

in your code you put int &refVal = ival well of course it will have the same address because &refVal is referring to the address of you variable therefore their address will be the same